# Simple MVVM Toolkit - loosing ViewModel when switching them

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, viewmodellocator

I'm using MVVM Toolkit.
In my ViewModels I'm keeping data which I'd like to save when switching ViewModel to another.

Responsible for switching ViewModels is ViewModelLocator:

http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started point 8.

ViewModelLocator everytime returns new ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    // Create ProductListViewModel on demand
    public ProductListViewModel ProductListViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            IProductServiceAgent serviceAgent = new MockProductServiceAgent();
            return new ProductListViewModel(serviceAgent);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to break MVVM rules. I was thinking about creating new objects like this:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private ProductListViewModel productListViewModel;

    // Create ProductListViewModel on demand
    public ProductListViewModel ProductListViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            IProductServiceAgent serviceAgent = new MockProductServiceAgent();
            if (productListViewModel == null)
                 productListViewModel = new ProductListViewModel(serviceAgent);
            return productListViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

... or while switching ViewModel serialize ViewModel, when loading it back - deserialize...

What is the proper solution of this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the data reside in the model? So when switching ViewModels you only have to make sure they access the same model file. This could be done by static access, a factory..

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to use any type of IoC container for that (for example Unity)

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public static UnityContainer Contaner { get; private set;}

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        Container = new UnityContainer();

        Container.RegisterType<ProductListViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    public ProductListViewModel ProductViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return Container.Resolve<ProductListViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

I think in MVVM Light Toolkit you have SimpleIoc - lightweight implementation of IoC container.

Comment: A model would be useful also. The view model contains view state, the model contains model data.